# Does anybody knows name of this bird I found in my backyard in India?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

I found this bird in my backyard in India. I checked several websites but wasn't able to identify it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open images.google.com drag and drop this image. It will says the answer

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure that this is a  [Indian Paradise-flycatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_paradise_flycatcher) (*Terpsiphone paradisi*). Since we cannot see the length of the tail feathers, we cannot distinguish between male and female, the later have a much shorter tail.

See the image (from [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/snapbyhimu/26750833273)) for comparision:

[image]

More information can also be found [here](http://www.oiseaux.net/birds/indian.paradise.flycatcher.html) and [here](http://datazone.birdlife.org/species/factsheet/indian-paradise-flycatcher-terpsiphone-paradisi).